# fql getting friends list error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Here is my query:

```
 fql?q=SELECT uid, name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

and here is the error:

```
(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference
```

Here is js code:

```
var query = encodeURI("SELECT uid, name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");
    FB.api('fql?q=' + query, function(response) {
        console.dir(response);
        if(! jQuery.isEmptyObject(response)&& ! jQuery.isEmptyObject(response.data)) {
            var maleList = $('#male-list');
            var femaleList = $('#female-list');
            for (var friend in response.data) {
                var item = STValentines.buildFriendItem(friend);
                if (friend.sex === 'male')
                    maleList.append(item);
                else
                    femaleList.append(item);
            }
        }
    });
```

Is it common problem ? Can I do anything about it ? 
Is there any walk around ? thank You for help

Comment: That is very odd.. Using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20pic_square%2C%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me()\)) - I **was able** to get data from this query.  This query is correct and the problem might be temporary.

Comment: If the problem persists you should defiantly file a bug with facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: It occurs only using javascript sdk from my app. Using Graph API Explorer doesnt raise any errors

Comment: Is it maybe an issue of escaping characters?  maybe you should try using the `escape()` method on your FQL query before handing it to the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Could You please write an example of this ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue of escaping characters.
You should try using the `escape()` method on your FQL query 
before handing it to the JavaScript SDK :

```
var escapedFQLQuery = escape('SELECT uid, name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())');
//escapedFQLQuery now is : "SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20pic_square%2C%20sex%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29"
FB.api(
  {
    method : 'fql.query',
    query  : escapedFQLQuery
  });
```

Comment: here is result: error_code: "601"
error_msg: "Parser error: unexpected '%' at position 6."

Comment: just throwing it out there - what happens if you don't use any method of escaping?  Try removing your call to `encodeURI()`

Comment: If I dont use any endoce, escape ... then I get: (#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference

Comment: another shot in the dark - try escaping the last closing bracket with a backslash to make it read like this : `(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()\)`

Comment: another option would be to substitute `me()` for the actual user id

Comment: tried everything and nothing. I think it may be problem on facebook :/

Comment: could be... check to see if there are any bugs open for the same problem (or a related problem with FQL).  If there is - subscribe to it. If there isn't - submit your form and wait for a reply from Facebook.